# How to test a function that calls other functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a method that gets data from local storage, and posts the data to the back end using axios.

```
 export const refreshAuth = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    getRefreshToken()
      .then(refreshJWT =>
        axios.post(`${API.auth}/refresh`, {
          refreshJWT
        })
      )
      .then((res: AxiosResponse<JWTData>) => {
        onSignIn(res.data.accessJWT, res.data.refreshJWT);
        resolve(res.data.accessJWT);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('failed to refresh the access token', err);
        reject(err);
      })
  );
```

I am creating a test suite using jest and currently am mocking axios to test the post method. How can I implicitly return a value from getRefreshToken()? In other words, how can I pass a value to refreshJWT while testing.

Comment: Mock that, too?

Comment: Can you provide some context, I am still learning jest. How would you return a value.

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api